# How to solve an equation with a sum operator...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I would like to solve the following equation with respect to $k$. I am not able to take $k$ out of the operator, hence any help will be appreciated.

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}[t_i^k \times \ln(t_i))]=y
$$

Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid that there is no way of expressing directly $k$ in terms of $y$ and the $t_i$.

Comment: Completely solving this will only be possible for $n=1$ itself